# MySQL php Linear Interpolation of Table

Tags: php, mysql, interpolation

I have a table titled "psytable_moist_air" shown below:
[image]

I'm trying to develop a MySQL statement that will interpolate a value that may be between records.  *(EDIT: If it is easier to do the math in PHP I'm open for that solution too!]*

**Example:** I would like to know the "hda" value where "T" = 17.8.

Notice there is no record where "T"=17.8. However, because this table is linearly related, I can get the "hda" value where "T"=17 and the "hda" value where "T"=18 and do a linear interpolation of the values.

The result math would look like this:
(Get the "hda" value where T=17 : hda = 17.102)
(Get the "hda" value where T=18 : hda = 18.108)

[image]

**EDIT**:
The only way I can think of is to do two MySQL statements to grab the smaller and larger values:

```
SELECT MAX(`T`), MAX(`hda`) FROM `psytable_moist_air` WHERE `T`<17.8
SELECT MIN(`T`), MIN(`hda`) FROM `psytable_moist_air` WHERE `T`>17.8
```

Then I would use these two values to do the interpolation. This works but seems pretty inefficient. Can anyone come up with a better solution??

If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated!

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way to do this would be to use the floor function.

See the following;

```
SET @x = 17.8;
SET @x0 = FLOOR(@x);
SET @x1 = FLOOR(@x) + 1;

SET @y0 = (SELECT `hda` FROM `psytable_moist_air` WHERE `T` = @x0);
SET @y1 = (SELECT `hda` FROM `psytable_moist_air` WHERE `T` = @x1);

SET @y = @y0 + (@y1 - @y0) * ((@x - @x0) / (@x1 - @x0));

Select @y ,@x0 ,@x1, @y0 ,@y1;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get all four values in one SQL statement? Also, your SQL statement works great for this example. But if I want to find the "T" value where "hda" = 17.562, then I cannot use this format. I'm just thinking ahead for future situations.

Comment: All 4 values (x1,x0,y1,y0) ? I updated the answer let me know.

Comment: Very interesting. But I received (@y=null, @x0=17, @x1=18, @y0=null, @y1=null)

Comment: Its not pulling the y0 and y1 values. Maybe I need to set the value of y0 first?

Comment: Fixed the statement. Apparently, the set in the select did not work properly  in that query. It should now return the results. Note, if the ID is out of boundary, it will return null as well.

Comment: Oh this is so beautiful...I created a php function that works but its so inefficient...this is pure MySQL and I love it. I'm going to click the checkbox 3 times even though 2 of them wont count.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do this and since there is no PHP answer:

```
function CalcLinearInterpolation($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $t){
        $n = ($x2 - $x1);
        $j = ((($t - $x1) / ($n / 100)) / 100);
        $r = $y1 + ($j*($y2 - $y1));                
        return $r;
}
```

`CalcLinearInterpolation(2, 5, 3, 9, 2.5)` would return 7

To be clear;

> - `2 (x1) = 5 (y1)`
> - `3 (x2) = 9 (y2)`
> - `2.5 (t) = Result`
>
> So: `CalcLinearInterpolation($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $t)` in this scenario;
>
> `CalcLinearInterpolation(2, 5, 3, 9, 2.5)`