# give average rating from 0 to 10 based on price

Tags: php, mysql, math

I have one product table having price as one of the fields. Now I want to calculate the rating for each product:

- Rating will be between 0 to 10.
- The product with the highest value will have a rating of 0 and the product with the lowest price will have a rating of 10.
- The number of products can be more than 100.

For example, there are 5 products with prices of 500, 40, 350, 100, and 60. So here product with a price of 40's rating is 10 and a product with a price of 500's rating is 0.

I am using MYSQL as my database and the frontend is using PHP.

**How can I calculate other products' ratings considering this min and max price? Can anyone suggest to me how to do this with MySQL?**

I have tried the following query. But in that, the highest price has 10 as a rating and the lowest price has 0 as a rating. But I want the lowest price product should have a 10 rating.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    IF (price=@maxprice, 10, (((price*10)/@maxprice)-((@minprice*10)/@maxprice))) as price_rating 
FROM products;
(SELECT @maxprice:= MAX(price) FROM products) as maxprice;
(SELECT @minprice:= MIN(price) FROM products ) as minprice ORDER BY price DESC;
```

Comment: Apart from this question being Off Topic becuase it is Too Broad, you dont say how you want to rank 98 products with a rank of 2 to 9

Comment: its not like rank. rating could be in decimal like 2.01, 0.94 etc

Comment: Have you made any attempts to complete this yourself? If so please provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempts.

Comment: @thodic I have edited my question and added query which i have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL php Linear Interpolation of Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282025/mysql-php-linear-interpolation-of-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what you want, but this will map your prices (linearly) to a range from 0 to 10, where 0 is the maximum price and 10 is the minimum:

```
SELECT @maxprice:= MAX(price) FROM products;
SELECT @minprice:= MIN(price) FROM products;

SELECT 
    id,
    10 - 10 * (price-@minprice) / (@maxprice-@minprice) as price_rating 
FROM products;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :)  Yes i want this only